# hibernate update JPA foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

My jpa looks like below

```
public class TESTClass implements Serializable {

    ...

    private String name;

    @EmbeddedId
    protected IssTESTPK issTESTPK;

    @ManyToOne(optional=false)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false), 
        @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUM", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUM", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false)})
    private IssDivision issDivision;

}
```

if i make change to 'name' and call merge, it able to update into database, but when i change issDivision, and call merge, it doesnt update database. how to solve this?

does it related to because i'm using embededId (composite primary keys) ?

### updated

if i set upadted=true, i get below error

```
ERROR - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(215) | Context initialization fa
iled
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean wit
h name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/application
Context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernat
e.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.compay.test.model
.TESTClass column: SURVEY_NUM (should be mapped with insert="false" update="fa
lse")
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBean
Factory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getOb
ject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistr
y.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBe
an(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean
(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.
preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:423)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finish
BeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refres
h(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationCon
text(ContextLoader.java:255)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationConte
xt(ContextLoader.java:199)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitiali
zed(ContextLoaderListener.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContex
t.java:3843)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4
342)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase
.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:77
1)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:525)

        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.ja
va:627)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.j
ava:553)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:488
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1149)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java
:311)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(Lifecycl
eSupport.java:117)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:719)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)

        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:443
)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:5
16)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710
)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:578)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
```

Comment: please give the whole classes (the entity and the embedded key)

Comment: @Bozho, can you post a example that is working entity with pk ?

Comment: i saw post at https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=973585&highlight=repeated+column+mapping+composite+fk, do you understand the last 2 post, regarding private get/set ?

Comment: Did this ever work for you? Please post the solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, Let's see

Your exception (and famous) message is

```
repeated column in mapping for entity:
column: SURVEY_NUM (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

Where does SURVEY_NUM column live ?

*1º* issDivision field stores a foreign key column called SURVEY_NUM

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE", insertable=false, updatable=false), 
    @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUM", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUM", insertable=false, updatable=false)})
private IssDivision issDivision;
```

Now, see the following mapping (**see both id and accountNumber shares the same column**)

```
@Entity
public class Account {

    private Integer id;

    private Integer accountNumber;

    @Id
    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    public Integer getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    @Column(name="ACCOUNT_NUMBER")
    public Integer getAccountNumber() {
        return this.accountNumber;
    }

}
```

Now let's do as follows

```
Account account = new Account();
account.setId(127359);
account.setAccountNumber(null);

entityManager.persist(account);
```

Hibernate will ask to you

> Which property should i persist **whether both properties shares the same column** ??? And as i can see, id property stores a non-null value and accountNumber a null value.

Should i perform a query like this one ???

```
INSERT INTO ACCOUNT (ACCOUNT_NUMBER, ACCOUNT_NUMBER) VALUES (127359, NULL);
```

It does not make sense. Therefore, it is a wrong SQL query;

Because of that, you see this nice message

> repeated column... blah, blah, blah... (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

So **i suppose** your compound primary key called IssTESTPK also stores a column called SURVEY_NUM. And **it is not a good idea** you define a compound primary key property as insert="false" update="false". Avoid a lot of headache.

Keep in mind: when more than one property shares the same column, define one of them as insertable=false, updatable=false. **Nothing else**.

I think your compound primary key class should looks like this one

```
@Embeddable
public class IssTESTPK implements Serializable {

    // Ops... Our missing field which causes our Exception (repeated column... blah, blah, blah...)
    @Column(name="SURVEY_NUM", nullable=false)
    private Integer property;

    private Integer otherProperty;

    private Integer anotherProperty;

    // required no-arg constructor
    public IssTESTPK() {}

    // You must implement equals and hashcode
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if(o == null)
            return false;

        if(!(o instanceof IssTESTPK))
            return false;

        IssTESTPK other = (IssTESTPK) o;
        if(!(getProperty().equals(other.getProperty())))
            return false;
        if(!(getOtherProperty().equals(other.getOtherProperty())))
            return false;
        if(!(getAnotherProperty().equals(other.getAnotherProperty())))
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    // NetBeans or Eclipse will worry about it
    public int hashcode() {
        // hashcode code goes here
    }

}
```

---

**UPDATE**

---

Before going on

> Hibernate **does not support** automatic generation of compound primary key

You **must** provide its values before saving. Keep it in mind

Let's see Employee compound primary key

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER")
    private String employeeNumber;

    @Column(name="SURVEY_NUMBER")
    private BigInteger surveyNumber;

    // getter's and setter's

    // equals and hashcode

}
```

*1º* Before saving an Employee, You **must** provide its values. As said above, Hibernate does not support automatic generation of compound primary key

*2º* Hibernate does not allow you update a (compound) primary key It does not make sense.

*3º* Its values can not be null

So, According to described above, our EmployeeId can be written as

```
@Embeddable
public class EmployeeId implements Serializable {

    @Column(name="EMPLOYEE_NUMBER", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private String employeeNumber;

    @Column(name="SURVEY_NUMBER", nullable=false, updatable=false)
    private BigInteger surveyNumber;

    // getter's and setter's

    // equals and hashcode

}
```

As said

> when more than one property shares the same column, define one of them as  insertable=false, updatable=false. **Nothing else**

But we can not mark a compound primary key property as insertable=false, updatable=false **because of Hibernate uses it to save our Entity**

As Hibernate will use our compound primary key property called surveyNumber (and its SURVEY_NUMBER column) to perform SQL operation on database, we need to re-write our @ManyToOne division property (and its foreign key column called SURVEY_NUMBER) as insertable=false, updatable=false

```
// Employee.java

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE"),
    @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)})
private Division division;
```

*4º* When you have a compound foreign key, **we can not mix** insertable-non-insertable or updatable-non-updatable.

Something like

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    // I can be updatable
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE", insertable=false),
    // And i can be insertable
    @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUMBER", updatable=false)})
private Division division;
```

Otherwise, Hibernate will complain

> Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed

Because of that, Its compound foreign key column called DIVISION_CODE **should also be marked** as insertable=false, updatable=false to avoid the exception shown above

```
// Employee.java

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE", insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)})
private Division division;
```

As we can not update DIVISION_CODE column anymore, our division property **behaves like a constant**. You, then, think of creating a new property called divisionCode to change, someway, DIVISION_CODE column, as follows

```
// Employee.java

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName="DIVISION_CODE", insertable=false, updatable=false),
    @JoinColumn(name="SURVEY_NUMBER", referencedColumnName="SURVEY_NUMBER", insertable=false, updatable=false)})
private Division division;

// Wow, now i expect i can change the value of DIVISION_CODE column
@Column(name="DIVISION_CODE")
private BigInteger divisionCode;
```

Well, Let's see. Suppose we have the following DIVISION TABLE

```
DIVISION TABLE
DIVISION_CODE     SURVEY_NUMBER
1                 10
2                 11
3                 12
4                 13
5                 14
```

remember: There is a foreign key constraint between Division and Employee

You think of

> **I can not change division** property because of insertable=false, updatable=false. **But i can change divisionCode** property (and its DIVISION_CODE column) as a way to change the foreign key column called DIVISION_CODE

You do the following code

employee.setDivisionCode(7);

Wow, see above in DIVISION_TABLE. Is There some value in DIVISION_CODE column equal to 7 ?

answer is clear: no (You will see a CONSTRAINT VIOLATION)

So, **it is an inconsistent mapping**. Hibernate does not allow it.

regards,

Comment: Hi, i did changes like you mentioned but it didnt work. i posted my original entities 
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/fvCSMNYlQt       (IssEmployee.java)
 
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/zJ14BVMqNq        (IssEmployeePK.java)

Answer (score 2):

It is because you are using `updatable = false`. Removing it might lead other problems, which I can't assume not knowing your complete mapping.

Set the `updatable` and `insertable` to `false` in the `Embeddable` class, and remove them from the join columns

Comment: @Bozho, i get other error when set updatable=true, i updated my question. that's why i must set updatable=false

Comment: TESTClass  http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/wuSaE04bvZ
composite keys  http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/ScH64kt9EY

Comment: @Bozho,  i saw your update, can you gie me sample example.. i dont quite understand what do u mean st embeddable class? which class issDivision?

Comment: @cometta - isn't @IssDivision `Embeddable` ? I assumed something that probably isn't true, but - give the code for `IssDivision`!

Comment: I posted my original entities
  http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/fvCSMNYlQt       (IssEmployee.java)
 
http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/zJ14BVMqNq        (IssEmployeePK.java)

Answer (score 1):

i found a workaround, but i like to hear from you all whether is ok to use this technique. i modify the entity class to..

```
public class TESTClass implements Serializable {

...
private String name;
@EmbeddedId
protected IssTESTPK issTESTPK;

    @JoinColumns({@JoinColumn(name = "DIVISION_CODE", referencedColumnName = "DIVISION_CODE", nullable = false , insertable = false, updatable = false), @JoinColumn(name = "SURVEY_NUM", referencedColumnName = "SURVEY_NUM", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)})
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private IssDivision issDivision;   //since this is not merge

       @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DIVISION_CODE")
    private String divisionCode;  //i add this

}
```

i added 'divisionCode' property, even though it duplicated inside issDivision object. but this is the workaround i able to update 'DIVISION_CODDE' when during merge